# 'Incompatible types: IntRange and Int' error in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin

Below is my code

```
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    println("Hello World")
    dayOfWeek()
}

fun dayOfWeek() {
    var date : Int = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE).toInt()
    when (date) {
        1..5 -> {
            println("Hello 1-5")
        }
        5 -> {
            println("Hello 5")
        }
        3, 7, 9 -> {
            println("3 7 9")
        }
    }
}
```

when I do this show's an error

> Incompatible types: IntRange and Int

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Note that ranges created with `..` include both endpoints.  (If you want to exclude the last one, use `until` instead.)  And that only the first matching block gets executed.  So (once you've got it to work by adding `in` as per the answers), "Hello 5" will never get printed, and "3 7 9" will only get printed for 7 and 9.  If you want _all_ matching blocks to be executed, use separate `if`s, not a `when`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you are extracting from Calendar is an `Int`. The `when` expression will try to match it with an `IntRange` type, which is represented by the literal `1..5` (more on that class [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/)). Those types are different, so hence the error

> Incompatible types: IntRange and Int

What you want is to ask if that *integer* is **in** that *range*, so you just prefix `in` to the range, as specified [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) for the usage of `when` with ranges.

So the code will look like

```
fun dayOfWeek() {
var date : Int = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE).toInt()
    when (date) {
        in 1..5 -> {
            println("Hello 1-5")
        }
        5 -> {
            println("Hello 5")
        }
        3, 7, 9 -> {
            println("3 7 9")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify `in` prefix before `range`

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello World")
    dayOfWeek()
}

fun dayOfWeek() {
    when (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE)) {
        in 1..5 -> {
            println("Hello 1-5")
        }
        5 -> {
            println("Hello 5")
        }
        3, 7, 9 -> {
            println("3 7 9")
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what is the use-case in your application, but note that second and third case will not execute when the date is either `3` or `5`